# Using Codeception with form input array

Tags: php, testing, codeception

So I am trying to use Codeception on a form where I have multiple inputs that have a name like such.

```
<input type="text" name="flavours[]" >
```

I have tried

```
$I->fillField('flavors[]', 'Blue Razberry');
```

However Codeception returns

```
Couldn't fill field "flavors[]","Blue Razberry":
InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field ""  unable to find a field with that name.
```

Is it possible in Codeception? If not, is there another way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever discover a resolution for this issue?

Comment: No dude. Ended up changing the architecture. I am waiting for codeception to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can you **submitForm method** instead

```
   $I->submitForm('#name_of_your_form', array(
    'field' => 'value',
    'field' => 'value'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
$I->fillField('flavors', 'Blue Razberry');
```